# Change directory command in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cd

In docker I want to do this:

```
git clone XYZ
cd XYZ
make XYZ
```

However because there is no cd command, I have to pass in the full path everytime (make XYZ /fullpath). Any good solutions for this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891669/docker-command-fails-during-build-but-succeeds-while-executed-within-running-co

Comment: WORKDIR command is noted as a possible workaround as well

Comment: Not a workaround, it's the recommended solution https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can run a script, or a more complex parameter to the RUN. Here is an example from a Dockerfile I've downloaded to look at previously:

```
RUN cd /opt && unzip treeio.zip && mv treeio-master treeio && \
    rm -f treeio.zip && cd treeio && pip install -r requirements.pip
```

Because of the use of '&&', it will only get to the final 'pip install' command if all the previous commands have succeeded.

In fact, since every RUN creates a new commit & (currently) an AUFS layer, if you have too many commands in the Dockerfile, you will use up the limits, so merging the RUNs (when the file is stable) can be a very useful thing to do.

Comment: In case you're wondering, the effect of the `cd` only lasts for the current `RUN` command. The next `RUN` will start from the current `WORKDIR`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an error that the directory doesn't exist. Only `WORKDIR` works.

Comment: This should not be the solution. The question is simply how to get CD to work.

Answer (score 837):

To change into another directory use [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir). All the RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT commands after WORKDIR will be executed from that directory.

```
RUN git clone XYZ 
WORKDIR "/XYZ"
RUN make
```

Comment: Using WORKDIR is also cited as a [dockerfile best practice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#workdir)

Comment: I believe this is a more appropriate answer to the question

Comment: Note that this creates multiple layers (I think?)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Tested and can confirm it works

Comment: I think that this answer is rather not enough. It did not help me in my case, it only helps in standard cases where you use for example `apt-get` or other commands that work in the `sh` shell (= Dockerfile default). If you need the `bash` instead of the `sh` shell, as it is normal for many bash commands that you also need in a Dockerfile, you need to call the `bash` shell before using the command. See [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66733880/11154841). The WORKDIR will not work in that isolated `bash`-`RUN`, the bash will start with the /root, if you do not change the ".bashrc".

Comment: Can I do: `WORKDIR "/XYZ/ABC"` if I want to `cd` into its subfolder?

Answer (score 31):

I was wondering if two times `WORKDIR` will work or not, but it worked :)

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./ ./

WORKDIR /usr/src/src

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Comment: For me it's not working...

Answer (score 5):

You can use single RUN command for all of them

```
RUN git clone XYZ && \
    cd XYZ && \
    make XYZ
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to change the working directory for the container when you run a docker image, you can use the `-w` (short for `--workdir`) option:

```bash
docker run -it -w /some/valid/directory/inside/docker {image-name}
```

Ref:

`docker run` options: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options

Answer (score 0):

**Mind that if you must run in `bash` shell, you need not just the `RUN make`, but you need to call the `bash` shell before, since in Docker, you are in the `sh` shell by default.**

Taken from [/bin/sh: 1: gvm: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448227/11154841), which would say more or less:

> Your shell is /bin/sh, but source expects /bin/bash, perhaps because it
> puts its initialization in `~/.bashrc`.

In other words, this problem can occur in any setting where the "sh" shell is used instead of the "bash", causing `"/bin/sh: 1: MY_COMMAND: not found"`.

In the Dockerfile case, use the recommended

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash'
```

or with the "`[]`" (which I would rather not use):

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash"]
```

**Every new RUN of a bash is isolated, "starting at 0". For example, mind that setting `WORKDIR /MY_PROJECT` before the bash commands in the Dockerfile does not affect the bash commands since the starting folder would have to be set in the ".bashrc" again. It needs `cd /MY_PROJECT` even if you have set WORKDIR.**

Side-note: do not forget the first "/" before "opt/../...". Else, it will throw the error:

```
/bin/bash: opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Works:

```
 => [stage-2 18/21] RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash"]                                  0.5s
 => [stage-2 19/21] [...]
```

**See [“/bin/sh: 1: MY_COMMAND: not found”](https://superuser.com/a/1634934/1192848) at SuperUser for some more details on how this looks with many lines, or how you would fill the ".bashrc" instead. But that goes a bit beyond the actual question here.**

PS: You might also put the commands you want to execute in a single bash script and run that bash script in the Dockerfile (though I would rather put the bash commands in the Dockerfile as well, just my opinion):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
```