# Docker File and execute phpize error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, phpize

When I try to build Docker File and execute `phpize` command, I get the error below.

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

Can't I use `phpize` in Docker file?

```
RUN apt-get install -qq -y php7.0-dev git pkg-config build-essential libmemcached-dev subversion

RUN cd ~
RUN git clone https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached.git
RUN cd php-memcached
RUN phpize && ./configure
RUN ./configure --disable-memcached-sasl
RUN make all install
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker: change directory command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632258/docker-change-directory-command). `cd` command doesn't do what you are expecting it to do when used with a `RUN` directive. Would you mind trying the answers from that question and see if that solves the problem?