# /bin/sh: 1: gvm: not found

Tags: go, docker, dockerfile, gvm

### Problem:

I'm attempting to create a Dockerfile that installs all the components to run Go, to install [GVM (Go Version Management)](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm), and to install specific Go Versions.

### Error:

When I try building the container with:

```
docker build -t ##### .
```

I get this error:

> /bin/sh: 1: gvm: not found
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c gvm install go1.4 -B' returned a non-zero code: 127

Installed here:

```
/root/.gvm/scripts/env/gvm
/root/.gvm/scripts/gvm
/root/.gvm/bin/gvm
```

### What I tried:

It's clearly able to install GVM but unable to use it. Why?
I thought maybe I needed to refresh the `.bashrc` or the `.bash_profile` ... but that didn't work, since they don't exist.

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM #####/#####

#Installing Golang dependencies
RUN apt-get -y install curl git mercurial make binutils bison gcc build-essential

#Installing Golang

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "bash < <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer)"]
#gvm does not exist here... why?
RUN gvm install go1.4 -B
RUN gvm use go1.4
```

### Question:

Why does GVM not seem to be installed? How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: Where is it installing `gvm`? Is it in your path? Why do you need `gvm` in a container, which is usually purpose-built for an application?

Comment: @JimB using it for developing reasons. Figured would be easier to handle go updates, check update for where GVM is installed. GVM usually gets added to the PATH automatically, no? It's not in the PATH, I'll add it later and see if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell is `/bin/sh`, but `gvm` puts its initialization in `~/.bashrc`, and expects `/bin/bash`.

You need to source the `gvm` initialization scripts to run the commands from a non-interactive bash shell:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". /root/.gvm/scripts/gvm && gvm install go1.4 -B"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", ". /root/.gvm/scripts/gvm && gvm use go1.4"]
```

Or even better might be to put the commands you want to execute in a single bash script and add that to the image.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

source /root/.gvm/scripts/gvm
gvm install go1.4
gvm use go1.4
```