# Point Dockerfile to specific folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm simply trying to get my dockerfile to point to a specific directory so that when I go to the URL I can do something like this: localhost:80/ask.PNG, and that image will render in the browser.

Currently my Dockerfile builds and runs, but when I try the above it states the files don't exist. Here is what I have.

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY / /MyPath/imagesfolder
```

The imagesfolder is saved within the same folder as my dockerfile and contains a few different images.

Comment: You're probably looking for the WORKDIR command. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632258/docker-change-directory-command

Comment: Also important to know `COPY / /MyPath` is copying your entire root directory (if on windows `c:/`) to the container,  `./` will copy current directory

Comment: Any update on this? Did you solve it

Answer (score 1):

According to [hub.docker.com/_/httpd/](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) you have to do something like this:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

You must copy your files to the specific location from which `httpd` is going to serve them and this is `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs`. Put your files there and it will work.

---

### Example

My folder structure (Dockerfile is the same with the above):

```
~/docker_tests/httpd$ tree
.
├── Dockerfile
└── public-html
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    └── 3.jpg

1 directory, 4 files
```

#### Build and run ...

```
docker build -t my-apache2 .
docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2
```

#### Access your files at

```
http://localhost:8080/1.jpg
http://localhost:8080/2.jpg
http://localhost:8080/3.jpg
```