# MySQL Setup using Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to create a setup where when I do a "docker run" off a Dockerfile that I've created, docker will install and setup mysql, and then create a database for me to use.

Below is my simple docker file that pulls from the existing [dockerfile/mysql](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dockerfile/mysql/)

```
FROM dockerfile/mysql
COPY dbsetup.sql /tmp/dbsetup.sql
RUN bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && \
  sleep 5 && \
  mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb"
```

It seems to run, but when I connect to the DB (using the IP I received from the `boot2docker ip` command), the database doesnt' exist.

Anyone have any ideas?

Note: I had originally tried to run all three of those commands in separate RUN statements, but that didn't work. [Explanation of why here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

You should take example on the [dockerfile/mysql Dockerfile](https://github.com/dockerfile/mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile) which has the following `RUN` statement:

```
RUN echo "mysqld_safe &" > /tmp/config \
    && echo "mysqladmin --silent --wait=30 ping || exit 1" >> /tmp/config \
    && echo "mysql -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \"root\"@\"%\" WITH GRANT OPTION;'" >> /tmp/config \
    && bash /tmp/config \
    && rm -f /tmp/config
```

In your case you would put in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "mysqld_safe &" > /tmp/config \
    && echo "mysqladmin --silent --wait=30 ping || exit 1" >> /tmp/config \
    && echo "mysql -u root -e \"CREATE DATABASE mydb\"" >> /tmp/config \
    && bash /tmp/config \
    && rm -f /tmp/config
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise either using the standard [mysql container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) image or borrow from its [dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/06bcb63a0b42ed24ef7509c3352e2cf45d139a5e/5.5)

It uses environment variables to control the database name and admin credentials.