# initialize google cloud sql from Docker file

Tags: sql, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a MySQL instance hosted in Google Cloud SQL, and I have a container which uses this database, I tried to initialize the database schema from the docker file using the following command:

FROM anapsix/alpine-java

```
ADD  ./mysql/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

init.sql

```
SET sql_mode = '';

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `locations_schema`;

USE `locations_schema`;


CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But unfortunately this is not working, is there any way I can achieve the init of a DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are getting confused implementing your solution.

If you have a unique Google Cloud MySQL instance used by your containers why are you trying to initialize the database schema each time a container is created from the new custom image? Isn't better to initialize it just connecting to it once manually?

However `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` is [used to initialize](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/#docker-secrets) local MySQL instances, not an instance running in a different machine. Notice that you will need at least to specify the address of the instance, a user and a password to let the container to connect to it. In order to do so there are different ways and you can find several guide, **but I don't think that this is what you need** to implement.

However If you are trying to init a MySQL instance running in the Docker container [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145370/how-can-i-initialize-a-mysql-database-with-schema-in-a-docker-container) you can find an awesome explanation how to do it, but I think you have to change the image you are starting from since I don't think that it contains MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script to do the initialize the DB without needing to pass the root password, provided MySQL is persisting data outside of the container and you specify a volume on the docker run command. You will need to specify environment variables specific to your environment. The script file needs to be added to the container via a Dockerfile. The Basic MySQL command line:

```
Set -e
Set -x
```

Then start the MySQL daemon

```
Mysql_pid=$!
```

You can add an echo for “..” to show until the MySQL admin has started, if you want.

```
mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION"
```

Then shutdown your MySQL daemon

```
wait $mysql_pid  --  wait for it to stop
```

The Docker documentation, https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/ offers more DB start options, including starting from an application in a docker container.  You can also combine MySQL and [docker commands](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Docker+CLI+Commands) for other database functions, like create schema, or creating multiple databases.