# Why isn't my docker-entrypoint-initdb.d script (as specified in docker-compose.yml) executed to initialize a fresh MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, init

I found out about the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44307918/4766), and also read the "Initializing a fresh instance" section of the ["How to use this image" MySQL documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). But when I run `docker-compose up` in the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file below, my database isn't initialized.

```
services:

# Use root/root as MySQL user/password credentials
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

I confirmed the `./mysql/init` directory contains a file named `init.sql`. And I confirmed that after I empty the `./mysql/data` directory and run `docker-compose up`, that a `db` database is created. But the database is not populated, unless I manually execute the script in Adminer. (I click on "Import", then choose the file and press the Execute button.)

I looked for messages in the console output after running `docker-compose up` that indicate an attempt to run `init.sql` and can't find anything.

**Update:** The MySQL version is 8.0.19.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Devil hides in details...

You have a double definition of `root` in your env vars. `root` user is created by default with password from `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`. You then ask to create a second "normal" user... with the exact same name and password (i.e. with `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`)

If you look carefully at your startup log, you will see an error

```
db_1       | ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
```

This actually stops further processing of your init files in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and goes on with the rest of the image startup process (i.e. restarting mysql after initialization on temporary server).

Simply drop `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` in your env vars, or set a different user than `root` and you will immediately see your init files processed (don't forget to empty your data dir again).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! I spent 2 days looking for an answer to this problem, and read all the possible answers in so much forums. that was it !