# How to terminate a MySQL container when an initialization script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` fails?

Tags: mysql, docker

When a MySQL container starts for the first time, `.sh` and `.sql` files under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are executed as a part of the startup process, according to [the official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

However, even if an initialization script (`.sh`) exits with a non-zero exit status, a container is not terminated and the remaining startup process proceeds. (This is also mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60021761/8776746).)

Normally I don't expect my initialization script to fail, so I want to regard any errors as *fatal* and terminate a container.

How can I do that?