# Dockerfile initialize mysql database, run script not found

Tags: mysql, docker, shell

I'm new to docker and trying to initialize MySQL database. I have been following the resources in:
[How can I initialize a MySQL database with schema in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145370/how-can-i-initialize-a-mysql-database-with-schema-in-a-docker-container)

My folder structure:

[image]

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql

# Copy the database schema to the /data directory
ADD files /tmp/

# init_db will create the default
# database from epcis_schema.sql, then
# stop mysqld, and finally copy the /var/lib/mysql directory
# to default_mysql_db.tar.gz
RUN chmod +x /tmp/init_db
RUN /tmp/init_db

# run_db starts mysqld, but first it checks
# to see if the /var/lib/mysql directory is empty, if
# it is it is seeded with default_mysql_db.tar.gz before
# the mysql is fired up


ENTRYPOINT "/tmp/files/run_db"
```

However, I'm getting an error when I try to run init_db script:

```
docker-compose up
Building db
Step 1/5 : FROM mysql
 ---> b5c10a3624ce
Step 2/5 : ADD files /tmp/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 442ac0d3181e
Step 3/5 : RUN chmod +x /tmp/init_db
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7f2a0abc246
Step 4/5 : RUN /tmp/init_db
 ---> Running in 7b4f397586f3
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/init_db: not found
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/init_db' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

When I do chmod in Step 3, it is able to find the file; however, failing to run in Step 4.

init_db:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialize MySQL database.
# ADD this file into the container via Dockerfile.
# Assuming you specify a VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"] or `-v /var/lib/mysql` on the `docker run` command…
# Once built, do e.g. `docker run your_image /path/to/docker-mysql-initialize.sh`
# Again, make sure MySQL is persisting data outside the container for this to have any effect.

set -e
set -x

mysql_install_db

# Start the MySQL daemon in the background.
/usr/sbin/mysqld &
mysql_pid=$!

until mysqladmin ping >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  echo -n "."; sleep 0.2
done

# Permit root login without password from outside container.
mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION"

# create the default database from the ADDed file.
mysql < /tmp/create_stock_data_db.sql

# create historical_data table
mysql < /tmp/create_historical_data.sql

# Tell the MySQL daemon to shutdown.
mysqladmin shutdown

# Wait for the MySQL daemon to exit.
wait $mysql_pid

# create a tar file with the database as it currently exists
tar czvf default_mysql.tar.gz /var/lib/mysql

# the tarfile contains the initialized state of the database.
# when the container is started, if the database is empty (/var/lib/mysql)
# then it is unpacked from default_mysql.tar.gz from
# the ENTRYPOINT /tmp/run_db script
```

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The run instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the existing image and commit the results.

So, each run instruction creates a new image and starts the `MySQL` server. Creating the database should be combined in the same `RUN` instruction.

`RUN chmod -R 775 /tmp/init_db`

Answer (score 0):

The [mysql docker library](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image already provides initialization.

Env `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1` will allow the root password to be empty.

Your two sql files need to be places in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and these will be loaded on startup. This can be exposed as a volume or creating a layered docker file.

See "Initializing a fresh instance" on the docker library link above.