# Docker container: /bin/sh: cat: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using the mysql/mysql-server image to create a mysql server in docker. Since I want to setup my database (add users, create tables) automatically, I've created a SQL file that does that for me. In order to automatically run that script, I extended the image with this dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:latest

RUN mkdir /scripts
WORKDIR /scripts

COPY ./db_setup.sql .
RUN mysql -u root -p password < cat db_setup.sql
```

but for some reason, this happens:

```
/bin/sh: cat: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c mysql -u root -p password < cat db_setup.sql' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `<` redirection operation takes a filename as an argument, not a command. You wouldn't be able to do the redirection above even without using docker. So thinking of this as a docker issue is a red herring.

Comment: You can't `RUN mysql` in any case, because the database server won't be running during the `docker build` phase.  Are you looking for something like the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` setup script directory?

Comment: @DavidMaze I know... I fixed it by using CMD but I know it’s not the best solution. Could you provide your solution?

Comment: The answers to [How can I initialize a MySQL database with schema in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145370/how-can-i-initialize-a-mysql-database-with-schema-in-a-docker-container) (but not the accepted answer) describe the setup pretty well.  Anything in that directory when the database container starts up the very first time will be executed, via `mysql` if it's a `*.sql` file.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate the good info in these comments that address how to run initialization scripts for the mysql image and not just mentioning the source of the original `cat: No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the `cat` command from your `RUN` command:

```
RUN mysql -u root -p password < db_setup.sql
```

`No such file or directory` is returned since `cat` cannot be found in the current directory set by WORKDIR. You can just redirect the stdin of mysql to be from the db_setup.sql file. *Edited* to clarify `<` sh redirection is expecting the file name to use for input.

EDIT 2: Keep in mind your example is a [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) command that is attempting to run `mysql` and creating a layer at docker image *build time*.  You may want to have this run during the mysql entrypoint script at *runtime* instead (e.g. [scripts are run](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c273193c14bb45daea2d27bb6ec51aa0b2b2ab9b/5.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L363) from the`docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory by the  [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/c273193c14bb45daea2d27bb6ec51aa0b2b2ab9b/5.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L53) script of the official mysql image) or using other features that are [documented for the official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

Comment: The cat command isn't necessarily missing from the image, but it's not an SQL file in the current working directory. So it can't be used as the input for the `<` redirection.

Comment: Ah, yes, correct, `<` would just be expecting the file name of the file to use for stdin. The `cat` is unnecessary, I'll clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`RUN` is a build time command. MySQL isn't running at this point.

If you where/are using a [standard image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) there is a location for database initialization:

```
FROM mysql:8.0
COPY db_setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Command cat is not present in mysql/mysql-server:latest image.

Moreover, you would only need to provide filename afetr redirection.

RUN mysql -u root -p password < db_setup.sql

Comment: First statement is not established. OP would get the same error even if the command did exist in the image, unless their current working directory is `/use/bin`

Comment: Even if the current working directory is  not /use/bin, but the location of cat should be added to path

Comment: `< cat` does not search the PATH, it looks for a file named `cat` in the current directory only; so whether it's in the path is irrelevant: The user would get a "file not found" for `< cat` no matter whether or not `/usr/bin/cat` exists (and no matter whether or not `/usr/bin` is in the PATH) as long as `/usr/bin` is not their current working directory.