# How do I initialize a MYSQL docker container with a .sql script?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have a .sql file that I want to run to fill the DB with data when I start up the container. How do I do it?

My docker scripts are below:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userpassword
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/
```

I have tried using this line in my Dockerfile

```
RUN mysql -usecret -pmydatabase mysql < /var/www/DB_Setup.sql
```

But I get the error

> /bin/sh: 1: mysql: not found
> ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mysql -usecret -pmydatabase mysql < /var/www/DB_Setup.sql' returned a non-zero code: 127

So I guess this is because the php container doesn't have mysql installed?

I guess I could use a Dockerfile with contents like this? But I'm not sure how to add it to docker-compose.yml?
Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145370/how-can-i-initialize-a-mysql-database-with-schema-in-a-docker-container)

```
FROM mysql:latest

MAINTAINER me

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mydatabase

ADD script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql#:%7E:text=Initializing%20a%20fresh%20instance):

> ## Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions `.sh`, `.sql` and `.sql.gz` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your `mysql` services by [mounting a SQL dump into that directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume) and provide [custom images](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable.

So, you can add another volume mapping to your mysql container:

```
- ./my-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

where `my-init-scripts` is a directory within the same directory that contains your composer file. Move your `DB_Setup.sql` file into `my-init-scripts` and it will be run when your container is started for the first time.