# How to import a database into a Docker container using docker-compose

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I am working with the official WordPress Docker image with docker-compose on my Mac (using boot2docker). I need to do a one-off data import. I'm not sure how to do this. How can I import data to the database container?

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme-name

db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile ?

Answer (score 28):

When using official Wordpress image, default name of the created database is `wordpress`.

So after you have deployed Wordpress application with docker-compose, you can import your wordpress database by

`docker exec -i db mysql -uroot -pexample wordpress < dump.sql`

Answer (score 3):

See this doc http://depressiverobot.com/2015/02/19/mysql-dump-docker.html and also this previous on SO [Setting up MySQL and importing dump within Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile)

Comment: Yes, I've seen those and cannot get them to work. I don't think they work in this instance (also considering running with docker-compose/boot2docker). Can you please provide an example command to run?

Comment: Can you provide details about "and cannot get them to work"?  Error messages and so. Installating Mysql and then launching a `docker exec -i dump mysql -uroot -proot < dump.sql` looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

copy your `.sql` or `.sql.gz` files into the mysql's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. It will automatically import the data into your database.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql