# ADD > LOAD .SQL using Docker Automated build and Compose

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

#### What is the optimal way to load in a sql dump when using docker-compose + docker automated builds?

Have been ignoring **docker-compose** for a moment and trying to understand docker and it's automated builds at first but have come to realize that i will probably need **docker-compose** if i want to accomplish my project goal that is to use one 1 command and from that have a fully working 3 site **Docker cluster**

1xHAProxy
3xUbuntu/wp
3xMysqld

In my Dockerfile i can just include the db.sql from my Github repo like

```
ADD db.sql /tmp/db.sql
```

Failing to find a best practise how i should load my DB without writing any commands outside of build.

### Want to know your solution to this using Dockerfile or Compose

By just executing one of the commands below a mysql **FROM** mysql with **ADD** db.sql db.sql should be build / run while loading db.sql in to mysql db wp
**Dockerfile**

```
$docker run -d user/repo:tag
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
$docker-compose up
```

If am totally on the wrong path here please give me some references. Could also mention that am planning to use CoreOS once i feel OK with Docker. So if best practices on a CoreOS > Docker setup is something else, let me know!

Comment: Why don't you want to just have another `RUN` command in the `Dockerfile` to load the database dump?

Comment: @AndyShinn How would that `RUN` look like?  Using suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile) will give me `The command xxx returned a non-zero code:`

Comment: Which suggestion specifically? The answer that question has an example for starting `mysqld_safe` and then importing the database in one compound `RUN` command. You will need to have `mysqld` started before you can import the database, which is specifically the problem that question is asking.

Comment: So @AndyShinn maybe you can give me an example how it should be done the right way.

Comment: Have a look at the "Initializing a fresh instance" section of the official MySQL image; https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/, that explains how to provide a SQL dump (or a shell script) that is automatically executed to initialize the database. You can mount those files as a volume, or bake them in an image for distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for initializing a SQL file during build or run time:

The first would be to just base your MySQL image on the official image and place your SQL file in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (using something like `ADD my.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` in the `Dockerfile`). The official image has a fairly complex entrypoint script (https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh) which starts MySQL, initializes a username and password, and scripts from the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder.

The other option would be to do something like the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920875/684908 and just add a command such as:

```
COPY dump.sql /tmp/
RUN /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && \
  sleep 5 && \
  mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb" && \
  mysql -u root mydb < /tmp/dump.sql
```

Comment: I'm not sure the second option would work, given that the MySQL image uses a`VOLUME` for the data-dir; so the database would not persist after build

Comment: Using following in Dockerfile did load my db.sql in to `ENV MYSQL_DATABASE` so there is some progress. 


`FROM mysql
ADD db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE mydb
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 123
ENV MYSQL_USER user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD 123`