# Populating Neo4J In Docker Container

Tags: docker, neo4j

I created a Docker container for Neo4J using

```
$ docker run --name my-neo4j -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
             -v ~/path/to/volume1:/data:rw -d neo4j:3.0.6
```

This, as expected, creates an empty graph database. For our use case, we'd like to have a pre-populated database.

Any help would be appreciated - preferably command line options, if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mount your graph.db in your neo4j? I'm not an expert in Neo4j but this seems an option to me.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at the example at https://dzone.com/articles/how-neo4j-data-import-minimal,

```
$ docker exec -i my-neo4j bin/neo4j-import --into /data/databases/person.db \
                                           --nodes:Person /data/people.csv \
                                           --relationships:KNOWS /data/friendships.csv
```

This will populate the `person.db`. To populate the default `graph.db`,

```
$ docker exec -i my-neo4j bin/neo4j-shell < ./local/path/to/setup.cql
```

where the `setup.cql` looks like

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///data/people.csv' AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR ',' 
MERGE (p:Person {person_id:line.personId, name:line.name});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data/friendships.csv" AS line 
FIELDTERMINATOR ',' 
MATCH (p1:Person),(p2:Person) 
WHERE p1.person_id = line.personId1 AND p2.person_id= line.personId2 
CREATE UNIQUE (p1)-[r:KNOWS]->(p2);
```

The 2 CSV files, `people` & `friendships`, have headers `personId,name` and `personId1,personId2` respectively.