# How to import mysql database using dokku

Tags: php, mysql, docker, dokku

I have an application in digital ocean using Dokku.

I created a mysql database that is linked to my application.

```
dokku mysql:create db_name
dokku mysql:link db_name app_name
```

The database structure is in a file on my computer. I sent the file to my droplet via sftp.

```
sftp root@ipmydroplet
put localdirectory/filename
```

When I try to import the bank structure it shows me this error.

```
dokku mysql:db_name < filename
```

Show this:

```
rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile

Comment: @Lucas, Jose's response should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The command:

```
dokku mysql:db_name
```

Isn't a valid command. What you want is the following:

```
dokku mysql:import db_name < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This command has an error:

```
dokku mysql:db_name < filename
```

It's missing the `import` command:

```
dokku mysql:import db_name < filename
```

**Suggestions:**

I always prefer to run my dokku commands from local, something like:

```
cat '/path/to/MYSCRIPT.sql' | ssh dokku@staging.YOURDOMAIN.tld mysql:import APPNAME < .
```

Hope you found it helpful.