# Can't MariaDB inside docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, mariadb

I need to run MariaDB inside existing Docker container.

Building and installation works just fine, but when Docker executes

```
RUN mysql < init.sql
```

to load DB schema I get

```
Can't connect to MySQL server (111 Connection refused)
```

However when I run the container and execute

```
docker exec -it silly_allen /bin/bash -c "mysql < init.sql"
```

it works just fine.

What might be the problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's part of Dockerfile related to DB.

```
FROM centos:7

WORKDIR /root

...
RUN echo "[mariadb]" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
RUN echo "name = MariaDB" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
RUN echo "baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
RUN echo "gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
RUN echo "gpgcheck=1" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
RUN rpm --import https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
RUN yum install -y MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
RUN yum clean all

RUN echo "[mysqld]" > /etc/my.cnf
RUN echo "bind-address=0.0.0.0" >> /etc/my.cnf

RUN /etc/init.d/mysql restart

ADD init.sql /root
RUN mysql < /root/init.sql
...
```

Comment: can you provide the full docker file?

Comment: it's pretty large. I can provide just the parts related to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you are trying to run `mysql < init.sql` before starting the database. The error shows that this command requires the database to be running.

To solve this problem, add a startup script into you container containing:

```
mysqld
mysql < init.sql
```

And change your Dockerfile CMD to call this script.

Answer (score 2):

According to Docker's best practices, you should be having 1 container per process that you want to run.

Also, there's an official [mariadb image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) which allows you to mount a directory as volume, that could contain SQL dumps. These dumps are auto-imported when the container gets created, so this might prove to be handy.

I'd suggest instead of having one very large dockerfile, you break it up in separate services with `docker-compose`

If you do however want to keep this the way it is, I'd suggest you move the `ADD init.sql ...` part to the top, and concatenate the server starting up part and the dump import, because each `RUN` command is a separate layer with Docker. So you'd need something like what's described in the answer of this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile):

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && \
  sleep 5 && \
  mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb" && \
  mysql -u root mydb < /root/init.sql
```

So that the server initializes and the dump gets imported in one layer

Answer (score 0):

This way is right:

```
# cat Dockerfile 
...
ADD init.sql /tmp
ADD initdb.sh /tmp
RUN /tmp/initdb.bash
CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql"]
```

And the script:

```
# cat dump/initdb.bash 
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

mysqld_safe --datadir='/var/lib/mysql' --user=root &
until mysqladmin ping >/dev/null 2>&1; do
   sleep 0.2
done

mysql -e 'create database init;' && \
mysql init < /tmp/init.sql && \
echo "Successfully imported" && exit 0
```