# Docker mysql issue

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I've read recent post [Setting up MySQL and importing dump within Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile) but couldn't find an answer.

What I want is to build custom mysql image with created database, users and some other data. Here is my Dockerfile(simplified):

```
    FROM mysql:5.7

    ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    RUN service mysql start && \
       mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" && \
       mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "SHOW databases;" && \   
       service mysql stop

ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && /bin/sh
```

Image is built successfully and mydb database is listed as output of "SHOW DATABASES".
But when I run container based on this image I see that root password is empty and mydb database is missing.

How can I fix that? Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  init scripts. It much more easier then Runing and Stopping mysql into RUN command

> **Initializing a fresh instance**
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. I will try that. But why my database created at RUN instruction was lost? Does it mean it doesn't make sense to initialize database-related data before first container run?

Comment: This is good question. Could you show me `Dockerfile` where you  use that base image?

Comment: Sergey, I specified Docker file contents in the question description

Comment: Yes, you show me base `Dockerfile`. But could you show also how do you use this base image?

Comment: I just run it using the following command: docker run -it mysql_db

Comment: Here is updated Dockerfile that shows MySQL databases during container startup:  FROM mysql:5.7

    ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

    RUN service mysql start && \
       mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;" && \
       mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "SHOW databases;" && \   
       service mysql stop

ENTRYPOINT service mysql start && mysql -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "SHOW databases;"