# Docker: How to import a SQL file into my local DB when using Docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am using Docker to run someone's app.  One of the containers is the web app and the sibling container is mysql.  I need to dump a table from the DB locally but I'm not sure how to connect to it.  I ran `docker inspect [container name]` on the mysql container and I see the IP address listed but now what do i do with that?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker exec {container} mysqldump {mysqldump option} > dump.sql
```

Hopefully mysqldump is in the container.