# Docker cloning mysql image for backup

Tags: docker, database-cloning

I am using a docker container that provides me a mysql database. I would like to make it as git branches. I wish to clone to container start it, make some db changes, then start another container in which all changes are discarded.

I was trying to use this post https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/ I created a container, then committed, created an image from container and then another container based on this new image.
Let's say I have db1, db2 containers.
I start db1 rename a table, stop it and then start db2. I wish that this table name is old. But after starting db2 I see the same table name as in db1. What I am doing wrong?
What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to have an independent container clone?

Comment: ...so you really should never use `docker commit`, and I'm impressed by the lengths that post goes through to work around its shortcomings.  You can't create an image based on the stock `mysql` image that contains a populated database but [Setting up MySQL and importing dump within Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920029/setting-up-mysql-and-importing-dump-within-dockerfile) includes the standard workaround.

Comment: I already set up the mysql. I am working on this database now I need to make some backup that I could restore e.g. tomorrow