# Script fails at build but works from Docker container

Tags: python, bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run unit tests through Docker for a directory monitor which reacts to file and directory creation, movement and renaming.

Here is the script :

```
#/bin/bash

# Launch Redis server
redis-server --daemonize yes
# Start directory_observer
python /test/directory_observer/src/directory_observer.py --config=/test/directory_observer/tests/directory_observer.ini &
# Execute test script (operations in the folders)
bash /test/directory_observer/tests/Dockerfile_testing/directory_observer_test_cases.sh
# Run Python unit test based on the operations executed above
python /test/directory_observer/tests/Dockerfile_testing/test_directory_observer.py
cd /test/directory_observer/ && nosetests
```

- `redis` is where the events noticed by the monitor are stocked
- `directory_observer.py` is the directory monitor
- `directory_observer_test_cases.sh` is just a bash script creating, renaming and moving some files and directories.
- `test_directory_observer.py` is just a Python unit test script (run here for debug purpose)

The problem is that some tests fail without any apparent reason at build, but if I try the exact same bash instructions from a running container, it works as intended.

If you need the code of `directory_observer_test_cases.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /test/monitored1

# Create, rename and delete file
touch file1
mv file1 rename1

# Same as above, but in a sub-directory
mkdir sub-monitored
cd /test/monitored1/sub-monitored
touch file2
mv file2 rename2

cd /test/monitored2

# Create, rename and delete file to test second monitored dir
touch file12
mv file12 rename12


### NOT MONITORED FROM HERE ###


# Rename the monitored directory
cd /test
mv monitored1 watched1

# Same as #1, but in the newly renamed directory
cd /test/watched1
touch file3
mv file3 rename3

# Move the second monitored directory
cd /test
mv monitored2 directory_host

# Same as #1, but in the newly moved directory
cd /test/directory_host/monitored2
touch file4
mv file4 rename4

# Operations in the non-monitored directory
cd /test/ingored.t
touch file5
mv file5 rename5
```

Be fore you ask, yes I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891669/docker-command-fails-during-build-but-succeeds-while-executed-within-running-co) but it doesn't help me there (or I'm missing something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, since the directory monitor was launched as a background process, the test script started before the monitor had initialized. Therefore, some events were missed and the tests failed.

Adding a `sleep 1` before launching the test script solved the problem and everything runs smoothly now.