# Compiling a module in docker fails during build but succeeds when run interactively

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and trying to create my first container to make the installation of a set of tools very simple. I'm using a miniconda2 on CentOS 7 base image, and using my own anaconda environment. My Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM conda/miniconda2-centos7

WORKDIR /home

#Install relevant dependencies with yum
RUN yum install -y (relevant packages)

#Set environment variables
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH .:/home/lib:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV PYTHONPATH /home/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
ENV HOME /home

#Copy the environment.yaml file and create the conda env
COPY environment.yaml /tmp/
RUN conda env create -f /tmp/environment.yaml
RUN echo "source activate environment" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/environment:$PATH
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV environment

#Install (module)
RUN mkdir /home/(module)
COPY <module> /home/(module)/
WORKDIR /home/(module)
RUN make all install
```

The build fails on the last line, and the error I run into is the following:

```
make: cython: Command not found
make: *** [cython/(module).cpp] Error 127
```

However, if I comment out the last line, build successfully, and run

```
docker run -it docker_test
(env) bash-4.2# make all install
```

The installation goes without a hitch. I have read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891669/docker-command-fails-during-build-but-succeeds-while-executed-within-running-co) but it hasn't helped me in my quest to build a working container!

One thought I have had is that somehow the anaconda environment is not activated while the container is being built (I followed advice online on how to use anaconda environments with docker), but when I start an interactive shell in the container the anaconda environment activates. I'm not sure how to debug this, however.

Comment: Each line in a dockerfile is executed in an independent shell, so your conda environment will not stay active from one command to the next. You could try stringing them together in one dockerfile command like
`RUN source activate environment && make all install`.

Comment: @Proyag This worked! Thank you. Out of curiosity, I would have that that the `echo "source activate environment" > ~/.bashrc` would have allowed each independent shell to run with the conda environment. Maybe changing the `HOME` environment variable created this problem? Or is there a separate reason?

Comment: I'm not very confident about the following, but to the best of my understanding: files like `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are not sourced during build-time.
Obscure source: [this issue on Github](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30066#issuecomment-272156425)