# How to download a specific git-lfs file into a Docker container

Tags: git, docker, github, docker-compose, git-lfs

I have a git repo with several large files. Git-LFS is enabled. I want to bring in one of the files into a Docker container. I have installed git-lfs in the container. So far I have:

```
RUN git clone --no-checkout --depth 1 https://github.com/my-org/my-data-repo.git
RUN cd my-data-repo
RUN git lfs pull -I data/my-large-file.csv
```

The file actually get's downloaded but the Docker build process fails because I get the following error:

```
Error updating the git index: (1/1), 90 MB | 4.8 MB/s                                                                                                                                                                                       
error: data/my-large-file.csv: cannot add to the index - missing --add option?
fatal: Unable to process path data/my-large-file.csv


Errors logged to .git/lfs/logs/20200709T142011.864584.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
```

How can do this without an exception being thrown which kills the Docker build process?

Comment: Looks like you are hitting this: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2937#issuecomment-407024556 if you use the `--no-checkout` flag, then you cannot pull a file anymore without breaking git's index

Comment: When I enable GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1, I still get an error: `Not in a git repository.`

Comment: how are you enabling GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1?  Can you post an update showing this in your question, it might help

Answer (score 2):

One of your issues is :

```
RUN cd my-data-repo
RUN git lfs pull -I data/my-large-file.csv
```

doesn't work as you expect :

- a first process is started, in which `cd my-data-reop` sets the current directory to `my-data-repo`,
- this process is then ended (along with its working directory)
- a second process is then started, which runs `git lfs pull ...` from the intital directory

---

You can either group your commands :

```
RUN cd my-data-repo && git lfs pull -I data/my-large-file.csv
```

or use the `WORKDIR` command (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870663/86072)) :

```
WORKDIR my-data-repo
RUN git lfs pull -I data/my-large-file.csv
```