# CD command is not working inside a docker container in ubuntu box :18.04(vagrant)

Tags: docker, devops

I am going to run MEAN stack app inside my container.I install git and clone the repo but when my iam trying to go inside the repo using cmd
RUN cd repo/ its not working however no error was thrown.

Below is the command using in dockerfile.

**RUN git clone https://github.com/AmitXShukla/Online-School-Management-App-Angular-Firebase.git**

****RUN cd Online-School-Management-App-Angular-Firebase/****

However if i go manually inside the container then this is working but i want to do from Dockerfile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker command fails during build, but succeeds while executed within running container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891669/docker-command-fails-during-build-but-succeeds-while-executed-within-running-co)

Comment: Since each `RUN` line starts a new shell (and a new container), `RUN cd` doesn't do anything.  Use `WORKDIR` to persistently change directories.

Comment: Try WORKDIR or try passing the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks all for the help i read the documentation later and find only way is  to use WORKDIR.