# Cant cd to cloned repo via Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, git-submodules

I'm creating a Dockerfile, but seem to be having some issues navigating to the folder of a cloned repo

My file contains the below

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER cagnulein

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
ENV MAKEFLAGS -j8
WORKDIR /usr/local/src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN apt -y update
RUN apt -y upgrade
RUN apt update -y && apt-get install -y git qt5-default libqt5bluetooth5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5xml5 qtconnectivity5-dev qtpositioning5-dev libqt5charts5-dev libqt5charts5 qt5-default libqt5networkauth5-dev libqt5websockets5* libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-xtest0-dev libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev build-essential
RUN cd ~
RUN git clone https://github.com/cagnulein/qdomyos-zwift.git
RUN ls -alh
RUN cd ~/qdomyos-zwift
```

I successfully clone the repo, and can confirm the folder exists, but I can't seem to navigate to it as I get the following

```
#13 [ 9/15] RUN ls -alh
#13 sha256:4b5dfb1969e228b79ed0f0d06393eddbc97c0197582b068ad75b1e5672597867
#13 0.361 total 16K
#13 0.361 drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.0K Mar 30 20:31 .
#13 0.361 drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4.0K Mar 16 20:07 ..
#13 0.361 drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4.0K Mar 30 20:31 qdomyos-zwift
#13 DONE 0.4s

#14 [10/15] RUN cd ~/qdomyos-zwift
#14 sha256:c875dc5e19a73f6e654af2feb63f14be8a945e8eefe4882f4cd64962dd90d399
#14 0.437 /bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /root/qdomyos-zwift
#14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd ~/qdomyos-zwift]: exit code: 2
```

Any ideas?

---

Tried

```
WORKDIR ~
RUN git clone https://github.com/cagnulein/qdomyos-zwift.git
RUN ls -alh
WORKDIR ~/domyos-zwift
RUN git submodule update --init src/smtpclient/
```

which fails with

```
#13 0.466 fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
#13 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git submodule update --init src/smtpclient/]: exit code: 128
------
 > [11/15] RUN git submodule update --init src/smtpclient/:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git submodule update --init src/smtpclient/]: exit code: 128
```

Comment: `WORKDIR /usr/local/src` … `cd ~/qdomyos-zwift`

Comment: Remove the `~/`. There's no need for it.

Comment: `RUN cd <anything>` doesn't do you any good. That's the same as trying to run something like `sh -c 'cd /somewhere'` in your local shell. Use `WORKDIR` to change directories.

Comment: @larsks Noted.   I tried this (updated) but then submodules are saying it's not a valid git repository

Comment: [Docker command fails during build, but succeeds while executed within running container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891669/docker-command-fails-during-build-but-succeeds-while-executed-within-running-co) also discusses the difference between `RUN cd` and `WORKDIR`.

Comment: I rolled back your recent edits. Ask a new question if you need help with a different problem (but it seems to have been a typo so I guess you figured it out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice in your example that you already have seen the mechanism to set the current directory: `WORKDIR`.

Replace all of your `RUN cd ...` statements with `WORKDIR /path` instead. That's the correct way to set the current directory in a Dockerfile.

If you need to be in another place at the end of your build, remember to add a `WORKDIR` toward the end of the file to leave that as the working directory in the final image.

Comment: I've just updated my question with the updated Dockerfile. It seems to navigate, but now the git submodule commands file as it fails to find the cloned repo?

Comment: @K20GH Are you sure the paths are all correct? I see your Dockerfile says `WORKDIR /usr/local/src/domyos-zwift` and then the git command has `/usr/local/src/domyos-zwift/src/smtpclient/` but your error is not the same - it seems to be trying to update `/usr/local/src/src/smtpclient/` (the repository name is now missing from the path).

Comment: Ahh, that's because I updated my edit Dockerfile after I noticed the issue. The error remains the same though, but has the repo name in the path

Comment: @K20GH I'd advise carefully reviewing all of the paths to make sure something wasn't missed

Comment: They're definitely correct.  I think maybe this is an issue with how `git submodules` work

Comment: You were correct. This answer was right, just might have helped if I didn't miss the q from the start of the folder name when navigating 

Answer (score 1):

Your `cd` manipulations seem confused and completely unnecessary. Probably try something along the lines of

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata
# RUN apt -y update  # no need, you just did
RUN apt -y upgrade
# RUN apt update -y &&  # no need, you just did
RUN apt-get install -y git qt5-default libqt5bluetooth5 \
     libqt5widgets5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5xml5 \
     qtconnectivity5-dev qtpositioning5-dev libqt5charts5-dev \
     libqt5charts5 qt5-default libqt5networkauth5-dev \
     libqt5websockets5* libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-xtest0-dev \
     libxcb-xinerama0-dev libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xkb-dev \
     build-essential
RUN git clone https://github.com/cagnulein/qdomyos-zwift.git
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/qdomyos-zwift
```

... assuming you would like to continue to run some commands in the directory you just cloned.

Comment: I've just updated my question with the updated Dockerfile. It seems to navigate, but now the git submodule commands file as it fails to find the cloned repo?

Comment: Ask a new question about that if you can't figure it out. Stack Overflow encourages you to update your question to provide full details, but you should only ask one question, and not change the essence of it once you have received answers.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is a shorthand for `$HOME`, the user's home directory. In this case this is `/root`. But as your `ls` command shows, the repo's directory is in the current directory. If you do `pwd`, you will see the current directory is not `/root`. Instead do `cd qdomyos-zwift` so that it is relative to the current directory.

Comment: The problem is that the OP expects `RUN cd ~` to do something that it doesn't actually do.

Comment: @larsks I think the OP doesn't understand what ~ means and was addressing the immediate error. You make a good point that fixing that error will probably lead to later problems because it still won't accomplish what the OP actually wants.