# Why do commands work using interactive container but fail in Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, docker, gcc, makefile, dockerfile

The following Dockerfile is adapted from this GitHub [comment](https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/6071#issuecomment-981298698):

```
FROM centos:centos7

#---------------------------------
#**gcc 8.2.0 :** 

RUN yum -y install wget bzip2 gcc gcc-c++ glibc-headers make
RUN yum upgrade -y ca-certificates
RUN mkdir /software
RUN wget -c -P /software/ https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.2.0/gcc-8.2.0.tar.gz

RUN cd /software/ \
 && tar -zxvf gcc-8.2.0.tar.gz \
 && cd gcc-8.2.0 \
 && ./contrib/download_prerequisites   
 
#result：
#gmp-6.1.0.tar.bz2: OK
#mpfr-3.1.4.tar.bz2: OK
#mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz: OK
#isl-0.18.tar.bz2: OK
#All prerequisites downloaded successfully.

RUN cd /software/gcc-8.2.0/ \
 && mkdir build \
 && cd build \
 && ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-8.2.0 --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib \
 && make 
#Can take up to 3 hours

RUN cd /software/gcc-8.2.0/build \
 && make install \
 && echo -e '\nexport PATH=/usr/local/gcc-8.2.0/bin:$PATH\n' >> /etc/profile.d/gcc.sh && source /etc/profile.d/gcc.sh \
 && ln -sv /usr/local/gcc-8.2.0/include/ /usr/include/gcc \
 && ldconfig -v \
 && ldconfig -p |grep gcc
#result: 
#libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1

#check version 
RUN gcc -v 

#------------------------------------
#**make 4.2.1:**
RUN cd /software \
 && make -v  \
 && wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-4.2.1.tar.gz \
 && tar -zxvf make-4.2.1.tar.gz \
 && cd make-4.2.1 \
 && mkdir build \
 && cd build \
 && ../configure --prefix=/usr \
 && sh build.sh \
 && make install \
 && make -v

#----------------------------------------
#**bison 3.0.4**
RUN yum install -y bison
RUN bison -V

#--------------------------------------------------------
#all prereqs complete, install glibc-2.28
#Download glibc-2.28 from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc into /software

RUN cd /software \
 && wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.gz \
 && tar -xf glibc-2.28.tar.gz \
 && cd glibc-2.28 \
 && mkdir build \
 && cd build \
 && ../configure --prefix=/usr --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/include --with-binutils=/usr/bin \
 && make \
 && make install \
 && ls -l /lib64/libc.so.6

#Check versions : 
#strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
#
#result:
#.....
#GLIBC_2.26
#GLIBC_2.27
#GLIBC_2.28
#GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

An error occurs in the final RUN block:

```
#17 2.197 configure: error:
#17 2.197 *** These critical programs are missing or too old: compiler
#17 2.197 *** Check the INSTALL file for required versions
```

However, no `configure` error occurs when I do the following:

- Create a Docker image from the above Dockerfile, minus the final RUN block.
- Create a container from this image using `docker run ...`
- Execute each command from the final RUN block interactively in this new container.

How can I resolve the difference between contexts - `docker build ...` and `docker run ...`?

I see other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17891972/7991646) recommending `cd` and `configure` within the same RUN block, but I'm already doing that.

The `patchelf` [approach](https://serverfault.com/questions/894625/safely-upgrade-glibc-on-centos-7) no longer works directly from yum and dnf package managers, but might be possible using Nix or Buildroot (see comments).

Also the `yum` package manager appears to break after the final `make install` command. Unsure why that is.

Comment: I can't explain the behavior you describe, but you seem to be going about this the hard way.  Perhaps you should be looking at this comment instead: https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/6071#issuecomment-1549437227.

Comment: It definitely feels like the hard way.. I made another Dockerfile to test the approach in your [link](https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/6071#issuecomment-1549437227). I'm unsure what that author's intent was. The container still shows GLIBC_2.17 as the highest installed version, which is the CentOS 7 default.

Comment: `source`ing a file only enacts its contents for the current shell, not any future ones.

Comment: That said, you seem to be reinventing a lot of wheels here, with respect to recreating things that [Nix](https://nixos.org/) or [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) can do for you.

Comment: (...and if you ask Nix to give you GCC 8, it'll immediately download a precompiled binary instead of making you wait for hours unless you ask for it to be compiled with patches or configuration or a target platform that's not already in the public cache; and patchelf is _very much_ actively supported in the Nix world).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I do `source` a file but it's in an earlier RUN block. When I enter commands interactively (no `configure` error occurs), I'm using a new shell. I'm working from a Docker image created from that whole Dockerfile *except* the final RUN block, which would throw a `configure` error if included with `docker build ...`.